# Imposible ejecutar comando 'python': ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, fedora

Estoy intentando trabajar en un proyecto con `Django` en `Fedora 30` y resulta que no puedo ejecutar nada relacionado con `python` porque obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

---

Mi versión de `python` por defecto es: `2.7.16`

Comment: no tienes la variable de entorno de python

Comment: PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"

Comment: Anteriormente intenté hacer set de la variable pero el error seguía

Comment: a lo mejor no esta instalado en ese directorio

Comment: whereis python
para ver donde esta instalado

Comment: cuando hago "which python" me devuelve /usr/bin/python , intenté colocar esa path en mi variable y el error persistía

Comment: y al ejecutar whereis me devuelve todo esto: "/usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m-x86_64-config /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python3.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7m"

Comment: Prueba con `unset PYTHONHOME`, o `export PYTHONHOME=/usr`

Comment: @FJSevilla hice `unset PYTHONHOME` y me funcionó, ahora, cuando quiero ejecutar python dentro de un env que utiliza la versión 3.5 me da un error diferente

Comment: `Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f8df86ed740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (`core' generado)
`

Comment: el error no es python el interprete por el error que te da , estas ejecutando un archivo que te falta instalar dependencias, verifica tu proyecto django tiene un archivo como requeriments.txt alli esta las dependencias

Comment: El proyecto no tiene requeriments.txt , ¿Entonces no hay forma de solucionar?

Comment: Umm no había visto el comentario sobre whereis ... ¿Tenias antes instalado Python 3 por defecto en el sistema y luego has instalado 2.7? El problema que comentas ahora me da a mi que es porque has terminado enlazando la biblioteca estándar de Python 2 con el interprete de Python 3 (encoding no existe en Python 2, es un módulo de la stdlib de Python 3)

Comment: Tenía el 2.7 por defecto y luego instalé python 3

Answer (score 0):

debes instalar el modulo site.

```
pip install site
```

Comment: Te recomiendo no exponer dudas en tus respuestas, ya que este espacio es solo para exponer soluciones